# Help with proving the Fatou's Lemma for discrete functions

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I need help to understand two steps in this proof for the Fatou's lemma in its discrete version.

Let $f_k:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0, \infty), k\in\mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of functions. Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \inf f_k(j) \leq \lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \inf \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_k(j), \forall j\in\mathbb{N},
$$
where $\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \inf f_k(j):= \lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}\left( \inf_{n \geq k} f_n(j) \right), \forall j\in\mathbb{N}$

The four steps for the proof are

i) For each $K\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a number $m(K)$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf f_n(k) \leq f_m(k) + \frac{1}{K^2}, \quad k\in\{1,\dots,K \},
$$
note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf f_n(k)$ might be $\infty$.

I guess I have to proceed here as in the "standard proof" for the continuous version, defining $g_n(k)= \inf f_n(k)$, and noting that $g_n(k) \leq g_{n+1}(k)$, fixing $K$ and $n$, I can always pick up a $m$ such that 
$$g_n(k) - f_m(k) \leq \frac{1}{K^2}, \quad k\in\{1,\dots,K \}, \quad m \geq m(K)$$.

But how to proceed when $n \rightarrow \infty$?

ii) Assuming that i) is true, with $m(K)$ chosen as in i), it is easy to show that for $k\in\{1,\dots,K \}$, and all $m \geq m(K)$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^K \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf f_n(k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^Kf_m(k) + \sum_{k=1}^K\frac{1}{K^2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_m(k) + \frac{1}{K}
$$

iii)

Conclude that for $k\in\{1,\dots,K \}$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^K \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\inf f_n(k) \leq \lim_{m \rightarrow\infty}\inf \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_m(k) + \frac{1}{K}
$$

I can not see this step, is this true? $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_m(k) \leq 
 \lim_{m \rightarrow\infty}\inf \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_m(k)
$$

iv)

Assuming that iii) is true, we can conclude the proof by letting $K\rightarrow \infty$.

Basically, I have problems to see the steps i) and iii). Any help? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For i) note that it is not worth considering the case when $\liminf f_n(k)=\infty$, because in this case the inequality becomes $\infty=\infty$. Note also that $m(K)$ is not unique. You can take a strictly increasing sequence of $m$'s which goes to $\infty$ and still have the desired inequality.

(The idea behind the liminf is that if $\liminf z_n=L$ then there is a subsequence of $z_n$ which converges to $L$, and any other subsequence has a limit greater than $L$.)

As for the proof for i), it is just the definition of $\liminf$. You could argue by contradiction. Fix $K$ and then suppose that there is no $m$ such that $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(k) \leq f_m(k)+\frac{1}{K^2}$. That means that the opposite inequality is true. Take the liminf and you get $0 \geq 1/K^2$.

In step iii) you just take a liminf of the inequality obtained in ii) as $m \to \infty$ (in fact i) holds for an increasing sequence of $m$'s). The left side does not depend on $m$ so it is unchanged, while in the right side you get what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Some questions. In i) $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(k) \leq f_m(k)+\frac{1}{K^2}$, why $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(k) = f_m(k)$?, $m$ is also fixed for a fixed $K$. I guess it is because if you take a sufficiently big $m$, this is true, because we assume in this case that $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(k) \neq \infty$, am I right? In iii) what is the liminf of the right side?

Comment: In i) if you argue by contradiction, then the reverse inequality is valid for every $m$, so you can take liminf as $m$ goes to $\infty$. in iii) you use ii) and take the liminf as $m$ goes to infty, and the answer is exactly iii).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. i) for me is clear now. For iii) you are saying to take the liminf in both sides right? because the left side does not depend on $m$, I can get rid of the liminf on the left side whereas I keep it on the right side. Is this correct? If yes, then I can say that my question is solved :P. By taking the liminf at both sides, how do I know this is not changing the inequality?

Comment: Taking liminf or limsup on an inequality does not change it (especially if one side is a constant).